# Why mathematica cannot get rid of Abs when all variables are positive and reals?

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I read a lot of old posts but still couldn't make it work. Hope someone could help me out. I am trying to simplify a square root expression with an assumption that all variables are positive reals. However, why the result sitll has `Abs`symbol?

```
vars = {Ao, C1, p, R}; 
$Assumptions = {vars > 0, Element[vars, Reals]}; 
FullSimplify[Sqrt[(1 + (1 + Ao)*C1*p*R)^2]]
$Assumptions = True;
```

Output:

```
Abs[1 + (1 + Ao)*C1*p*R]
```

Expected output:

```
1 + (1 + Ao)*C1*p*R
```

Comment: `$Assumptions = Flatten@{Thread[vars > 0], Element[vars, Reals]}`

Comment: Note that the assumptions mechanism is smart enough to know that if you're using inequality relations, the variables are already assumed real. Thus: `Assuming[Thread[{Ao, C1, p, R} > 0], FullSimplify[Sqrt[(1 + (1 + Ao)*C1*p*R)^2]]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to rewrite the `$Assumptions` in the following form

```
vars = {Ao, C1, p, R};
$Assumptions = And @@ Thread[vars > 0] && Element[vars, Reals];
FullSimplify[Sqrt[(1 + (1 + Ao)*C1*p*R)^2]]
$Assumptions = True;
```

Output (as expected):

```
1 + (1 + Ao) C1 p R
```